# Setting up a class to contain a list of objects

Tags: c#, web-services, class

I am setting a class in C# to hold a response that I will be receiving from a web service call. I'm using RestSharp to handle the calling / parsing of the JSON data.

The web service documentation describes the response as:

```
OUTPUT: JSON object similar to example below.
    {
        "response":"[success] or [failed]",
        "messages":"Process succeeded.",
        "logonkey":"[logon key]",
        "tokenkey":"[security token]",
        "reccount":"1",
        "filelist":
            {
            "fileid":"12345",
            "status":"N",
            "filename":"data.tar",
            "fulfilled":"2012-06-15"
        }
    }
```

My question is how can I define the filelist array element in my class?

I was thinking something like this:

```
public class Files
{
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public string Messages { get; set; }
    public string LogonKey { get; set; }
    public string TokenKey { get; set; }
    public int RecordCount { get; set; }
    public List<FileList>
}

public class FileList
{
    public string FileID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fulfilled { get; set; }
}
```

However, I'm having a problem with the "public List" statement.

Any suggestions on the best way to handle this scenario would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem with public list more exactly?

Comment: The code, as above, will not compile (unexpected token error after <FileList>). I cannot add the {get; set;} elements either (invalid token error).

Comment: because you need to add the getter and the setter to that list as well.

Comment: That returns an error -- cannot resolve symbol get (or set)

Comment: Also you forgot to give it a name For example try this public List<FileList> MyFavouriteList {get;set;}. A proprety is declared like this "access modifier", "Type", "identifier(or name)", "getter and setter".   If you want i can give you an article or write it as code like an answer.

Comment: Added my answer if you wish to mark it as the good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filelist in JSON sample doesn't look like list of objects. Instead it is a single object.
You could try,

```
public class Files
{
    public string Response { get; set; }
    public string Messages { get; set; }
    public string LogonKey { get; set; }
    public string TokenKey { get; set; }
    public int RecordCount { get; set; }
    public FileList File   {get; set; }
}
```

If you are sure the filelist in JSON is really list of object, you could try,

```
public List<FileList> Files   = new List<FileList>();
```

Comment: Sorry for the poor JSON code example. It is possible that FileList will contain multiple objects. In that case the RecordCount would be greater than 1 and the FileList would contain several objects.

Comment: Thanks Vetti -- thank solution works. As Freeman pointed out above, I was forgetting to name the object. public List<FileList> FileList {get; set;}  works.

Comment: If you use property like, List<FileList> FileList {get; set;}, make sure you initiaze it before accessing them.

Answer (score 2):

Also you forgot to give it a name, for example try this

```
public List<FileList> MyFavouriteList {get;set;}.
```

A proprety is declared like this "access modifier", "Type", "identifier(or name)", "getter and setter".